# Chazon Ish neurosurgery diagram

Tags: history, rabbis, medicine, chazon-ish

There is a well-known story about the Chazon Ish, where someone who was scheduled to undergo a neurosurgical procedure came to him for advice, and the Chazon Ish drew a diagram for the surgeon indicating how the surgery should be performed. A few years ago I saw a copy of the diagram in a certain sefer, but can no longer remember where. Anyone know where it could be?

(If we find it, the next question will be who can interpret it!)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30393

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://dovbear.blogspot.com/2010/08/follow-up-hazzon-ish-and-his-famous.html

Comment: Thanks! For those who are interested, here's a direct link to the reproduction of the diagram in Yeshurun: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21194&pgnum=504

Comment: The diagram in the artscroll biography is very different and was of the brain.

Comment: I think that one was also supposed to be the brain. Are you sure the one in Artscroll is different?

Comment: If you have access to it, could you scan and upload?

Comment: I do not have access to the Artscroll biography at the present, but I clearly remember that the sketches were a series of circle diagrams mapping the procedure to remove a brain tumor. They looked quite different than this one but it could be artscroll just printed part of the diagrams, such as the map for getting to the tumor but not the actual brain structure itself.

Comment: @Yahu The diagram you are referring to (p. 142) is on hilchot kiddush hachodesh, there is no diagram of the brain in my edition (Jan '12) of the artscroll biography of the Chazon Ish

Answer (score 9):

It appears in the Artscroll biography (or hagiography) of the Chazon Ish. I know the widow and children of the man (who was a *bochur* at the time) who had the brain tumor and required the operation.

A surgery sketch is mentioned in the newly translated biography of Rav Shach (in the 500's), not as a "*Daas Torah*" plug, but rather matter-of-factly, that the Chazon Ish entrusted sketches of organs for a surgery to Rav Shach to deliver to the Brisker Rav. Based on the sketch in Yeshurun it is possible that there is more than one instance in which the Chazon Ish provided sketches for surgeries.

Comment: Another Medical story of the Chazon Ish in this Shiur an its amazing solution all the way at the end of Shiur The Person is an M.D.
http://www.simpletoremember.com/media/a/torah-cause-and-reality/