# Chazon Ish and Medicine

Tags: medicine, historical-figures, chazon-ish

I have recently studied the Chazon Ish's work Emunah U'Vitachon and in the opening pages, the Chazon Ish displays a vast knowledge of human anatomy. Also, [the Chazon Ish successfully mapped out a plan for a neurosurgeon to successfully complete an operation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2542). Where did the Chazon Ish learn so much about human anatomy and medicine? Could it be that the Chazon Ish studied medical books?

As always, please cite your sources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I mention on [my post](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/06/is-it-important-how-chazon-ish-knew.html) on this very topic, Rabbi Slifkin [reported the following](http://www.cross-currents.com/archives/2009/06/24/a-y-karelitz-m-d/):

> I once asked Rav Gedaliah Nadel z”l, one of the foremost talmidim of the Chazon Ish, about the Chazon Ish’s medical knowledge. He told me that the Chazon Ish’s knowledge came from reading medical journals.